# Linux shell script - Is it possible to capture the output of a command and use it in another command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell-scripting

So I want to automate the process of uploading a file to Rackspace.  Here's what I need to do:

First, I type:

```
 curl -D - \
        -H "X-Auth-Key: 123456789abcdefghijk" \
        -H "X-Auth-User: MyUsername" \
        https://auth.api.rackspacecloud.com/v1.0
```

This gives me back a response such as:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
vary: X-Auth-Token,X-Auth-Key,X-Storage-User,X-Storage-Pass
X-Storage-Url: https://storage101.ord1.clouddrive.com/v1/BlahBlah
Cache-Control: s-maxage=46818
Content-Type: text/xml
Date: Tue, 07 Feb 2012 05:07:09 GMT
X-Auth-Token: SOME_AUTH_TOKEN_I_NEED
X-Storage-Token: blahblah
X-Server-Management-Url: https://servers.api.rackspacecloud.com/v1.0/123456
Connection: Keep-Alive
X-CDN-Management-Url: https://cdn2.clouddrive.com/v1/BlahBlah
```

Next, I need to upload a file:

```
curl -X PUT -T foo.txt -D - \
     -H "ETag: 7849eb8d56581fa7c4896bb0db64892c" \
     -H "Content-Type: text/plain" \
     -H "X-Auth-Token: SOME_AUTH_TOKEN_I_NEED" \
     -H "X-Object-Meta-Screenie: Test" \
     https://storage101.ord1.clouddrive.com/v1/BlahBlah/MyBackup/foo.txt
```

So basically, I need to parse the auth token (X-Auth-Token) as well as the storage URL (X-Storage-Url) and build the next command dynamically.

Is there a way to do that with a shell script, perhaps using regular expressions or something?  Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's surely a more elegant solution than this, but off the top of my head, a quick and dirty  bash way of doing it would be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

xauthtoken=`curl -D - \
        -H "X-Auth-Key: 123456789abcdefghijk" \
        -H "X-Auth-User: MyUsername" \
        https://auth.api.rackspacecloud.com/v1.0 | grep X\-Auth\-Token | awk '{print $2}'`

xstorageurl=`curl -D - \
        -H "X-Auth-Key: 123456789abcdefghijk" \
        -H "X-Auth-User: MyUsername" \
        https://auth.api.rackspacecloud.com/v1.0 | grep X\-Storage\-Url | awk '{print $2}'`

curl -X PUT -T foo.txt -D - \
     -H "ETag: 7849eb8d56581fa7c4896bb0db64892c" \
     -H "Content-Type: text/plain" \
     -H "X-Auth-Token: ${xauthtoken}" \
     -H "X-Object-Meta-Screenie: Test" \
     $xstorageurl
```

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up just writing this as a Python script instead and it works much better.  I'll save this for future reference though!

Comment: please post your python solution as well!